# How do I remove a duplicate tag created by a question that has since been migrated?

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process, migrated-questions

I recently noticed the creation of the tag [url](/questions/tagged/url) on meta.  This tag is a duplicate of the existing tag [urls](/questions/tagged/urls) (a synonym of [hyperlinks](/questions/tagged/hyperlinks)).  The issue isn't that I can't edit the question that created it (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278182/url-parsing-with-does-not-work) to change it to an existing tag since the question has been migrated.
Additionally, on Meta Stack Exchange, [`url`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/url/) **is** a synonym of [`hyperlinks`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/hyperlinks/), while it isn't here.

How should I deal with the duplicate tag, given that I don't have enough reputation to propose a synonym?

Answer (score 4):

You don't *have* to do anything. The migration "stub" will be [removed automatically after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year), and if there are no other questions using that tag then the tag itself [will be deleted within 31 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121191/what-are-all-the-reasons-a-tag-can-be-eliminated-automatically).

If it's really bothering you, then earn [the reputation necessary to suggest a synonym.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) You're *almost* there...